# useRef syntax in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was working on a basic project in React, and found this snippet of code which introduces useRef to take the reference of a canvas element. I am new to this and cannot figure out how this line works.

```
const canvasRef = (useRef < HTMLCanvasElement) | (null > null);
```

Any help or reference regarding this would be highly appreciated. The rest of the snippet for the canvas is below.

```
export interface ICanvasBoard {
  height: number;
  width: number;
}

const CanvasBoard = ({ height, width }: ICanvasBoard) => {
  const canvasRef = (useRef < HTMLCanvasElement) | (null > null);
  const [context, setContext] =
    (useState < CanvasRenderingContext2D) | (null > null);

  useEffect(() => {
    //Draw on canvas each time
    setContext(canvasRef.current && canvasRef.current.getContext("2d")); //store in state variable
  }, [context]);

  return (
    <canvas
      ref={canvasRef}   
      style={{
        border: "3px solid black",
      }}
      height={height}
      width={width}
    />
  );
};
```

I have tried looking for the syntax as well as tried running this code. The useRef line does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is wrong. It should be like this:

`const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);`

Here we are declaring a ref called `canvasRef` and we tell TypeScript that this will refer to an `HTMLCanvasElement` using the type parameter (the thing in angle brackets). Refs to DOM elements are initialized with `null`.

The line declaring the context state is also wrong - it should be like this:

`const [context, setContext] = useState<CanvasRenderingContext2D | null>(null);`

Possibly some sort of auto-formatting could have printed the code like this.

Comment: yes that fixes the syntax, but storing the `context` as state is actually a mistake here. any function that interacts with context needs to read it from `canvasRef` directly.